# boto3 list security groups associated with ec2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

is it possible to list out all security groups associated with an EC2 instance with `boto3` ? if so how is this done?

I have tried the following methods but they are not doing what I want:

```
for region in regions:
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    try:
        payload = client.describe_security_groups(Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': ['vpc-*']}])
        for sg in payload["SecurityGroups"]:
            if sg["Description"] != "default VPC security group":
                resp = client.describe_security_group_references(DryRun=False, GroupId=[sg["GroupId"]])
                print resp

    except Exception as E:
        print region, E
        continue
```

```
for region in regions:
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    try:
        payload = client.describe_security_groups(Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': ['vpc-*']}])
        for sg in payload["SecurityGroups"]:
            if sg["Description"] != "default VPC security group":
                sg = json.dumps(sg)
                pp(sg)
                # x = requests.post(url=sumocollector, data=sg)
                # print x.status_code

    except Exception as E:
        print region, E
        continue
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for a list of SGs for each instance, then I'd do `describe_instances` instead:

```
for region in regions:
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    try:
        response = client.describe_instances()
        for reservation in response['Reservations']:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']:
                print("Instance: " + instance['InstanceId'])
                for securityGroup in instance['SecurityGroups']:
                    print("SG ID: {}, Name: {}".format(securityGroup['GroupId'], securityGroup['GroupName']))

    except Exception as E:
        print(region, E)
        continue
```